# Autoplay not working in mobile android

Tags: android, jquery, jquery-mobile, jwplayer6

I am using jwplayer in my application, it works fine on my desktop, but on mobile (Android) the autoplay is not working. I need this functionality, I also tried jQuery by trigger to click, touchstrat, tap but not working

Answer (score 0):

JWPlayer does not support autoplay on mobile devices.

> Note that autostarting does not work on mobile phones (Android, iOS), since a fullscreen video takeover would be a jarring experience. Video also swiftly depletes 3G/4G bandwidth allowances.

Source: http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1428525-autostarting-on-page-load